# Angular pwa, how can I make http-server (running on localhost:8080) to work with a nodejs server running on localhost:3333?

Tags: angular, proxy, angular-pwa

When I serve the web-app on port 3330, I can make the webapp working on port 3333 using --proxy ./src/proxy.config.json, but I don't know how to make http-server to make to work at the same way

```
"start": "ng serve -o --port 3330 --watch --proxy-config ./src/proxy.config.json",
"pwa": "http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/satoshi-pwa --proxy http://localhost:3333",
```

proxy.config.json:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3333",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/"
    }
  }
}
```

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3333/api'
};
```

Comment: Do you find a solution?

Comment: I am also looking solution for this issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: is there any other server that will be useful for this scenario?

Comment: @BohdanSkochko no I haven't